# SQL - Show post (5 hours ago)

Tags: mysql, sql

Right now im making a post plugin to wordpress where I would like to display how many hours/days its been since the post was created.

I want this output /

```
Post Example1:
Author: Admin
Title: Fary Lochan Batch 03
Description: Fary Lochan Efterår Batch 03 48,3% Danish Single Malt Whisky ...
Created: 45 days

Post Example2:
Author: Admin
Title: Trolden Distillery – Nimbus No. 6
Description: Nimbus No. 6 – Danish Single Malt Whisky 46% ...
Created: 2 minutes ago
```

Right now im display the date with this sql string:

```
select c.description, c.date, e.display_name 
from ".$this->tables->tableEmployee()." e, ".$this->tables->comments()." c 
where c.customer_Id = 404 
and e.id = c.employee_Id
```

Im getting this output right now

```
Post Example1:
Author: Admin
Title: Fary Lochan Batch 03
Description: Fary Lochan Efterår Batch 03 48,3% Danish Single Malt Whisky .
Created: 2019-12-05
```

Can u help me? :)

Comment: `I want this output` ... the output you are showing us would best be handled in your presentation layer (e.g. PHP), not in MySQL.

Comment: Ohh okay. I would try that.

Comment: Just a remark. But if the "date" column is a date type, then it seems  kinda odd to [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) the difference in minutes against the current datetime.